# i18n-js and React Native : Use json files instead of .js files for translations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react native app I'm using "i18n-js": "^3.9.2" in order to have translations, I'm only able to get them to work properly using .js files for each locale like this:

es.js

```
export default 
{
    currency:"€",
    rememberToUnsuscribe:"Recuerda que si estas suscrito
}
```

It works fi ne but I'd like to use .json files instead of .js files, how can I do that? is it even possibe with this library?

This is my i18n.js file, where I bootstrap the translations.

```
import I18n from "i18n-js";
//import {  AsyncStorage  } from 'react-native';

import en from "@locales/en";
import es from "@locales/es";


I18n.fallbacks = true;
I18n.translations = {
  en,
  es
};

if (Array.isArray(locales)) 
{
    I18n.locale = locales[0].languageTag;
    console.log('I18n.locale',I18n.locale);
}

export default I18n;
```